# Pass variable of Rails to a Partial error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Im try pass a variable by the my rails partial but this error

```
SyntaxError in Posts#index

Showing /Users/overallduka/Blog1/app/views/posts/_posts_mason.html.erb where line #5 raised:
Extracted source (around line #5):

2:  
3:     <%= link_to "Add to Journal", add_post_journal_path(@post), :method => :put %>
4: 
5:     <h2><%= link_to @post.title,post_path(@post) %></h2>
6: <%= image_tag @post.image.url,:class => "thumb" %> <br>
7: 
8: <%= @post.content  %>
```

im try exibe this partial _posts_mason.html.erb

```
  <div id="post"  >

    <%= link_to "Add to Journal", add_post_journal_path(@post), :method => :put %>

    <h2><%= link_to @post.title,post_path(@post) %></h2>
<%= image_tag @post.image.url,:class => "thumb" %> <br>

<%= @post.content  %>

  <br>
  <p>Por <%= @post.user.email %> em <%= @post.created_at.strftime("%d %b. %Y") %> ás <%= @post.created_at.strftime("%H:%M") %></p>



  <div id="post_footer">


  <%= link_to_function "Comentar","
  $(this).fadeOut();
if($('#comment_form_#{@post.id}').css('display') == 'none')
{
$('#comment_form_#{@post.id}').slideDown();
}
else $('#comment_form_#{@post.id}').slideUp();
$('.comentar.#{@post.id}').hide();
",:class=>"comentar"

%>

<div id="comment_form_<%= @post.id %>" style="display: none;" >

  <%= form_for [@post,@post.comments.build], :remote => true do |com| %>
      <%= com.text_area :comment %>

      <%= com.submit 'Comentar' %>


  <%end %>
  </div>


      <div class="comment_list <%= @post.id %>">
  <% @post.comments.each do |comment|   %>

      <% if comment.comment %>
                <div id="comments">
      <%= comment.user && comment.user.email %>:
           <%= comment.comment %>
                </div>
          <%end%>



   <%end%>

      </div>

<br>



  </div><!--Fim div #post_footer-->


</div>
```

Im pass the variable of the loop each, this code:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>


<%= render :partial => "posts_mason",:locals => { post => @post } %>


<% end %>
```

what is wrong, before transform the content in partial are working perfect i dont know what is wrong please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the help, i solve the problem but whit the :collection

i change my partial name to _post.html.erb

and change my variables @post by post in partial

but a note, the partial variable passed by collection need be same name of the partial,

by example if my partial calling _post_mason.html.erb, my variable in partial must be post_mason, i wait all understand me , this solve my problem, the variable passed by the :collection must be same name of partial.

Thanks for the answers all help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error at line 5 in `_posts_mason.html.erb`

replace :

```
<h2><%= link_to @post.title,post_path(@post) %></h2>
```

with:

```
<h2><%= link_to("#{@post.title}", post_path(@post)) %></h2>
```

Change your loop to:

```
<%= render :partial => "posts_mason",:collection => @posts %>
```

Comment: Works more or mine, all the @post dont works in the partial and are error.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning wrong variable in last piece of code. Should be local **post**. You could monkey patch it like this to work:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% @post=post %>
  <%= render :partial => "posts_mason" %>
<% end %>
```

But **the correct way to do this is** to assign local variable to partial like this (replace each block):

```
<%= render :partial => "posts_mason",:collection => @posts %>
```

..and use local variable **post** in your partial _posts_mason.html.erb e.g.:

```
<h2><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></h2>
```